# Django: object has no attibute 'id'

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

When saving the object it show error like:

```
'feed' object has no attribute 'id'
```

And here is my code:

form.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import feed

class feed_form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = feed
        fields = ('feed_text',  )
```

models.py

```
class feed(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True,blank=True)
    feed_text = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    date =0 
    upvote = 0
    downvote = 0

    def __str__(self):
        return feed.content

    def __init__(self):
        date = timezone.now()
```

views.py

```
def upload(request):
    feed_cont = feed_form(data=request.POST)
    feed_cont.save(commit=False)
    feed_cont.user = User.objects.get(pk =1)
    feed_cont.upvote = 0
    feed_cont.downvote = 0
    feed_cont.save()
    return render(request,'feeds/feeds.html')
```

Where i made the mistake here? Am i using the foreign key method in right way? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the `__init__()` on the super class to let django initialize your model correctly:

```
class feed(models.Model):
    ...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(feed, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        date = timezone.now()
```